# add item and fill DropDownlist from db

Tags: c#, asp.net

Add a `---select---` item and fill DropDownlist from db

```
 if (cboAssignTo != null)
 {
         GetUsers();
         cboAssignTo.DataSource = GetActiveUsers(dstAuthUsrList).Tables[0];
         ListItem lstItm = new ListItem("New", "");
         cboAssignTo.Items.Insert(0, lstItm);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i would set the proterty `AppendDataBoundItems` true and add one empty value

**.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboAssignTo" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
     <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

then you can bind data

**.cs**

```
cboAssignTo.DataSource = GetActiveUsers(dstAuthUsrList).Tables[0];
cboAssignTo.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have inserted the empty element, you need to **bind** the dropdown before inserting the new element.

```
if (cboAssignTo != null)
 {
         GetUsers();
         cboAssignTo.DataSource = GetActiveUsers(dstAuthUsrList).Tables[0];
         cboAssignTo.DataBind(); // Add this statement
         ListItem lstItm = new ListItem("New", "");
         cboAssignTo.Items.Insert(0, lstItm);
}
```